# How to implement parallelism in this bash one-liner

Tags: bash

Can someone help me tidying up this dirty one-liner and implementing parallelism?

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec rename 's/\.php$/.txt/' '{}' \; && chown www-data:www-data -R * && chmod 0755 -R * && find . -name "*.html" -exec rename 's/\.html$/.txt/' '{}' \; && find . -name ".htaccess" -delete
```

Comment: It's rather hard to introduce parallelism when everything is dependent on all the preceding steps because your commands are chained by `&&`, so you can't do any later steps until all the preceding ones have succeeded.

Comment: They are currently dependent, but I see no reason for that dependency. If the dependency is not really needed, just start all the finds in parallel and, afterwards, the chown/chmod in parallel too (if done all at the same time, chmod/chown will complain about missing files and some files won't be processed.).

Answer (score 6):

Adding parallelism to an I/O bound set of tasks will only make it slower if the parallel tasks share the same I/O channel. (Hint: they do here.)

The only useful optimization you can do here is reduce the number of times you traverse the same directory tree.

```
find . -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \; \
  -exec chmod 0755 {} \; \
  \( -name "*.php" -exec rename 's/\.php$/.txt/' '{}' \; \
  -o -name "*.html" -exec rename 's/\.html$/.txt/' '{}' \; \
  -o -name ".htaccess" -delete \)
```

This could still be tweaked but e.g. avoiding to `chown` a file you know you are going to delete is small potatoes compared to reducing five directory traversals to one.

Comment: Just trying to learn... why does the `{}` parameter to `rename` require single quotes when the parameters to `chown` and `chmod` do not require quotes, please?

Comment: It doesn't really require them; I kept them when I copy/pasted those parts of you cnde, but a pair of braces does not actually require quoting. (Other braces may, in Bash.)